# Javascript Map and Reduce with Sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary, reduce

In this line of code which concats two arrays and multiplies each value by 2:

```
[[3,2,1],[6,5,4]].reduce(function(p,c,i,a) {
    return p.concat(c) 
}).map(function(v) {
    return v * 2 
}).sort()
```

I would expect the final output to be sorted, but it is not.  The result is:

```
[10, 12, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

If I put the sort in earlier, it comes back sorted:

```
[[3,2,1],[6,5,4]].reduce(function(p,c,i,a) {
    return p.concat(c) 
}).sort().map(function(v) {
    return v * 2 
})
```

Result:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

What is going on here?  This is not a duplicate question, as noted below.  And the duplicate cited is incorrect as well.  .sort will indeed sort numbers:

```
[10,12,2,4,6,8].sort() = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/arr-sort-does-not-sort-integers-correctly

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, the referenced duplicate is a different question, and the answer is also incorrect.  Javascript sort prototype will indeed sort numbers.

Comment: What browser are you using where `[10,12,2,4,6,8].sort()` gives you `[2,4,6,8,10,12]`? It gives me `[10,12,2,4,6,8]` in Firefox 34.0. Not entirely convinced it's a duplicate question, though, since that other one doesn't address why calling `sort()` and `map()` in different orders affects the results.

Comment: The problem is essentially the same. If you sort first, the array you're sorting is `[3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4]`, but if you sort last, the array you're sorting is `[6, 4, 2, 12, 10, 8]`, and because `sort` uses alphabetical sorting by default, you'll get different results. (i.e. `2` < `12` but `"12"` < `"2"`)